# What Is difference between .net core 2.2, 3.0, and 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

can someone please tell me what are the breaking changes in dotnet core 3.1?

Comment: In short: More apis  (new and ported from .NET Framework). Hard to tell in details, up to 20k apis were added from 2.0 to 3.0

Comment: What do you mean no details are given? There are lots of post from Microsoft and also from other sites and companies which explain the versions in great details. You should maybe read the preview blogs, they give some insight you don't get in other blogs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is far too broad, no matter how many details someone provides, there are more lurking.

Comment: Api diffs can be seen on github: https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/master/release-notes in the 2.x/api-diff/xxx folders

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Forgive me for sounding annoyed, but Googling for ".net core changelist" returns these results immediately:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-1

Each of these pages says exactly what's changed and added.

Now, finding differences between .NET Core 3.0 and 3.1 is harder - I admit - as it's still in Preview so the postings only detail the changes between Preview releases, however the Preview 1 release notes( https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/preview/3.1.0-preview1.md ) do list the Notable changes indirectly via links to tagged GitHub issues at the bottom.

- .NET Core 3.1 CLR non-bugfix changes: 
  https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A3.1+label%3Aenhancement
- .NET Core 3.1 BCL non-bugfix changes: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A3.1+label%3Aenhancement
- .NET Core 3.1 ASP.NET Core non-bugfix changes: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A3.1.0-preview1+label%3ADone+label%3Aenhancement

Comment: Plus https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/master/release-notes/3.0/api-diff/.Net for detailed api list of newly added or ported apis

Comment: That was truely my question, sorry my bad for asking too broad question which got too many downvotes :,(. i want to know the breaking changes as it is a bit confusing as they are too close (3.0, 3.1). My bad sorry

Comment: Thanks for the docs, will check them :)

Comment: @TheCondorIV For ASP.NET Core breaking changes are listed in https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones. .NET Core itself shouldn't have much of breaking changes itself, since its a runtime. In doubt check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/breaking-changes, i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#corefx